# Firebase Database - Not getting data

Tags: json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data in a database on firebase like this:
[image: stuff]

But when I use this code to retrieve it, I don't get any errors... or data...

```
      function startTest(qId) {
    var gotQType = qId.slice(0, 3);
    firebase.database().ref().child("questions").child(gotQType).child(qId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
      var datas = snapshot.val();
      var qTitle = datas.questionTitle;
      var explan = datas.explanation;
      var imageUrl = datas.questionImageUrl;

      $("#questionimg").attr("src", imageUrl);
    });
  }
startTest("NVR1");
```

Comment: try to join the query piece by piece firs get the data upto questions node and see if it contains an snapshot If it does then get its child.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @marmadukeandbob change ur rules to read:true and write:true

Comment: Have in mind that the public (read:true and write:true) rules are only meant for testing. Do not leave your database public in production